# How do I change an element using Jquery based on what it is

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I have a simple span with a number inside it:

```
<span id="MessageLabel">@Model.MessageCount</span>
```

How do I hide the number if the value is 0 and display the number if the value is greater than 0?

This is what I have so far:

```
function loadMessageCount() {

    $('#MessageLabel')

        if ($(item.val()) <= 0) {
             $('#MessageLabel').hide();
        } 
}
```

I may also need to do this through ajax since the page doesn't get loaded every time that number changes. Is it also possible to do that?

Comment: with a `span` you have to use `text()` and not `val()`

Comment: You could also use the parseInt() to convert the text from the span element into an integer for a cleaner solution.

Comment: As Diodeus seems to be ignoring you, I've added a way to change the text to red at the bottom of my answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15641428/1317805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first want to assign `$('#MessageLabel')` to the variable named `item`:

```
var item = $('#MessageLabel');
```

[`spans` do not have `values`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element). `.val()` is used to pull values. Here you'd want to use `.text()`:

```
...
if (item.text() <= 0) { ... }
```

You'd first want to ensure that this is an integer, however, using `parseInt()`:

```
...
if (parseInt(item.text()) <= 0) { ... }
```

You may want to check out the official jQuery tutorial: http://try.jquery.com :-)

> How would I change the color of the text to red if the number is greater than 1?

```
if (parseInt(item.text()) > 1) {
    $(this).css({
        'color': '#f00';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close:

```
function loadMessageCount() {    
    var item = $('#MessageLabel')    
        if (parseInt(item.text()) <= 0) {
             item.hide();
        } 
}
```

Comment: ...and item instead of $(item) the second time.

Comment: This works like a charm! How would I change the color of the text to red if the number is greater than 1?

Comment: Create a CSS class, then use item.addClass('yourname');

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
if(parseInt($('#MessageLabel').text()) > 0)
{
    $('#MessageLabel').show()
}
else
{
    $('#MessageLabel').hide();
}
```